# How do I delete a record?

Tags: nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-2, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to delete a database record using ASP.NET MVC, Fluent, and NHibernate. See the code below for examples of how I'm trying to accomplish this. I am able to Get, Update, and Insert records but Delete is not working. When the Delete() method gets called in the controller (top one) it throws an Exception (`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'Styles'.`).

I would like to avoid any sort of meta-SQL query because I don't want to hard code the table name into the controller if I don't have to.

**Controller snippet**:

```
// POST: /Brand/Delete/5
// Here is the handler in the controller
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection)
{
    try
    {
        IRepository<Brand> repo = new BrandRepository();
        repo.Delete(id);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

**Repository snippet**:

```
//Here is the repository
//The insert/update/get/etc all work fine
void IRepository<Brand>.Delete(int id)
{
    using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
    {
        using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            IRepository<Brand> repo = new BrandRepository();

            session.Delete(repo.GetById(id));
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

**Mapping snippet**:

```
//And here is the mapping for a Brand
public class BrandMap : ClassMap<Brand>
{
    public BrandMap()
    {
        Table("Brands");
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.Name);
        HasMany(x => x.Styles)
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

Comment: What exception is thrown? As far as hardcoding is concerned, you've already hardcoded a repository in your controller so your code is tightly coupled with NHibernate. Catching an exception without actually doing something with it like for example logging it is very bad practice. Also why on earth are you creating a new instance of `BrandRepository` inside the `Delete` method which as it looks is already part of this class?

Comment: It's kind of hard to figure out which exception is thrown because I have to return a view or else it won't build

Comment: Well put a `catch (Exception ex)` and debug what the value of `ex` is, or even better, remove the `try/catch` block and leave the exception propagate.

Comment: These 3 code snippets are separate files. The formatting on Stackoverflow doesn't let me separate them very easily. I'll try to edit it

Comment: Ok, good point. See my edits please

Comment: Alright. I'm retarded. My table is named `Shoes` and I thought I changed it to `Styles` but apparently not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the mapping of the `Styles` property is incorrect. Are you using a correct table name? From the exception it seems that there's no such table `Styles`.